Market data custom indicator
Please, is there a (easy) way in pine to get to binance (market) trading data (such as oi, l/s ratio etc/) - to build a custom indicator? Any example/manual article (link to)? Thanks.
Just can’t (understand where to) find right ‘symbol’ for request.security()… Or custom ticker identifier maybe?

Using the symbol search menu you have access to all data available on Tradingview.
Try searching for "Binance_", "BTC_" or "Doge_" etc and scroll through the results, there seems to be an abundance of data available for cryptos. I added 3 screenshots with examples.
You can then use "exchange:symbol" to call this data with request.security(), for example to get the "total amount of transactions" for BTC your request is
transactions_btc = request.security("GLASSNODE:BTC_TXS", "1D", ...)



